# ASP files are not served in asp.net 4.0 and 64 bit project

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp-classic

Getting HTTP 500 while requesting the ASP files which are deployed in 64bit server and the application uses .net 4.0 framework. Can any one have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried a generic asp page to confirm it's IIS and not a script error? What does the IIS log or event viewer show as the error detail.It should be working.

Comment: What version of Windows server are you using?

Comment: Is there any other detail in the 500 error?  Can you see entries in the eventlog the correspond to the time you are getting the error?

Comment: @Bill Martin/@AnthonyWJones: this is the problem with all asp files. Below are error log:   Exception message: Server operation is not available in this context.
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String path)
   at lmsportal.Global.Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: using windows server 2003 R2.

Answer (score 1):

In your IIS configuration (role features) you will need to ensure that ASP is enabled. The application pool would need to be classic and in most cases in advanced properties of application pool you will need to enable 32 bit applications (if you use any older activeX controls)

Hope that helps

(Turning off friendly errors in IE and restarting the browser will most likely yield more info)

Comment: Why classic?  The integrated pipeline has a ASP handler.

Answer (score 1):

Control Panel > Administrative Tools > IIS. Under your servername, select 'Web Service Extensions' On the right, set 'Active Service Pages' to 'Allowed' and do an iisreset.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you do not have .aspx files registered in Handler Mappings in IIS for the site

Comment: This question is about running classic asp pages not aspx pages